# Scheme, generating states to solve a 2x2x2 rubick's sphere

Tags: scheme

For a scheme assignment I need to write a brute force solver for a 2x2x2 rubick's sphere.

Half of the sphere can turn in positive/negative x, y and z directions.

My function genStates is meant to take in a state and generate 6 states from it saving the moves to reach those states in a second list (with matching indices to access later)

A state is a list of positions and directions ((1 1) (2 1) (3 1) (4 1) (5 3) (6 3) (7 3) (8 3)) and is coupled with a moves list ("x" "Y" "y" "Z").

My problem is that I can't seem to save the states and moves in the way I'd like.

```
(list
    (list
        ;all states
    )
    (list
        ;all moves
    )
)
```

My genStates function

```
(define (genStates n state moves)
    (if (= n 0)
    ;if last recurse just return current state
        (list state moves)
    ;else call helper
        (genHelper n (generateSuccessorStates state moves))

    )
)
```

My genHelper function

```
(define (genHelper n state)
(list
    (append 
        (genStates (- n 1) (index (car state) 0) (index (cdr state) 0))
        (genStates (- n 1) (index (car state) 1) (index (cdr state) 1))
        (genStates (- n 1) (index (car state) 2) (index (cdr state) 2))
        (genStates (- n 1) (index (car state) 3) (index (cdr state) 3))
        (genStates (- n 1) (index (car state) 4) (index (cdr state) 4))
        (genStates (- n 1) (index (car state) 5) (index (cdr state) 5)))
)
)
```

This method seems to return the states as ("x" "X" "y" "Y" "z" "Z") just before each 6 lines of states instead of as lists of moves at the end.

I have been able to produce the correct output using print statements and forking each time without appending to a list but I'm unsure how to collect the data from the recursive calls.

My generateSuccessorStates function

```
(define (generateSuccessorStates state prevMoves) 
(list
    (list
        (rotate "x" state)
        (rotate "X" state)
        (rotate "y" state)
        (rotate "Y" state)
        (rotate "z" state)
        (rotate "Z" state)
    )
    (list
        (append prevMoves '("x"))
        (append prevMoves '("X"))
        (append prevMoves '("y"))
        (append prevMoves '("Y"))
        (append prevMoves '("z"))
        (append prevMoves '("Z"))
    )
)
)
```

To any of my classmates who may likely see this, I am of course fine with you using my ideas but please don't just copy paste my code into your project. That will end badly for everyone involved.

Comment: Note that `append` can take more than two arguments as in  `(append xs ys zs)`. You can improve gen-helper using this fact.